# Azure Shared Access Signature (SAS) token security

Tags: url, azure, access-token

I'm learning Azure Storage and I am doing my best to make sure access from Internet is as safe as possible.

When I generate a connection string there is a SAS token embedded in the URL.
That token has different permissions parameters and they are signed with the service private key.

But I don't understand how putting this SAS token in the URL is safe. If I launch such a URL with the token in it, what prevents it to be read by a network sniffer or proxy? If the URL can be read then I see no security in Shared Access Signatures. So I must be missing the point.

Is there any chance the parameters after the ? in the URL aren't sent and kept for the client? If so, I guess we have to rely on the client security and trust it. Am I right?

Thank you

Comment: It's unclear since pages like this one: https://technicqa.com/are-url-parameters-encrypted-over-https/ do state "URLS and query parameters aren’t secure. They should never contain sensitive or important information (passwords, static shared secrets, private information, etc)." Yet, I read parameters after the ? mark aren't sent before the https/TLS handshake is done. So I'm still a bit confused at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use HTTP**S** then the SSL/TLS will protect against a network sniffer. The URL cannot be read, but it might be possible to retrieve it from your browsing history - so be aware if you use a shared PC.

An encrypted HTTPS request protects most things:
This is the same for all HTTP methods (GET, POST, PUT, etc.). The URL path and query string parameters are encrypted, as are POST bodies.
https://https.cio.gov/faq/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/643480/1042624